# mitsubishi pajero 3.5L petrol 2002 model

Tags: mitsubishi, pajero

Pajero was running rough so I had the plugs and cables changed no difference, so had the fuel injectors changed and a new gasket, seems to be sucking air somewhere drives ok but coughs and splutters at idle anyone have any ides???

Comment: Checked the air filter? Checked the compressions?